# lua: iterate through all pairs in table

Tags: loops, lua, lua-table

I have a sparse lua table and I need to iterate over it.  The Problem is, it seems that lua begins the iteration at 1, and terminates as soon as it finds a nil value.  Here's and example:

```
> tab={}
> tab[2]='b'
> tab[5]='e'
> for i,v in ipairs(tab) do print(i,v) end
>               --nothing is output here
> tab[1]='a'
> for i,v in ipairs(tab) do print(i,v) end
1   a
2   b
>               --terminates after 2 (first nil value is tab[3])
```

Is there any way to get the desired output:

```
1   a
2   b
5   e
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You must use `pairs` instead of `ipairs`.

```
tab={}

tab[1]='a'
tab[2]='b'
tab[5]='e'

for k, v in pairs(tab) do print(k, v) end
```

Will output (in any order):

```
1   a
2   b
5   e
```

`ipairs` iterates over sequential integer keys, starting at 1 and breaking on the first `nil` pair.

`pairs` iterates over all key-value pairs in the table. Note that this is *not* guaranteed to iterate in a specific order.