# [lua]: Key with value 1 doesnt do the same as regular 1

Tags: lua

Ive been coding for a mod Im making for a game but I ran into an issue with tables not returning values when the key is entered:

```
for k, v in pairs(self.math) do
    print(self.exce[1])
    print(self.exce[k])
    print(k)
    if self.exce[k] ~= nil then
        self.math[k] = nil
    end
end
```

This is the specific part of the script that is breaking. When I run these in the game it returns:

```
[lua]: true
[lua]: nil
[lua]: 1
```

Which means is basically saying that 1 is not equal to 1.
The function I used to store my data is

```
function filterExceptions.server_onException( self, id )
    if self.exce[id] == nil then
        self.exce[id] = true
        self.network:sendToClients( "client_onList", id )
    else
        self.exce[id] = true
        self.network:sendToClients( "client_offList", id )
    end
end
```

In this code the self is a table made by the game you can acces and get game data from or store it in and the id comes from a function I made to get the players id. This id in this case is a 1 (I printed it multiple times).I know that every part of this code is working except for the code in the first block, and escpecialy the part where it tries to do `self.exce[k]`. Ive tried a lot like going trough every variable in `self.exce` to see if it was in there and then do stuff, but it still wouldn't work. Its very annoying how lua thinks that k ~= 1 while it definitely is, ive even used similar code in a part that is working.

So what is wrong about this code that its not printing the `self.exce[k]` while `self.exce[1]` does work? Dont worry about the creation of the table and stuff, cuz that is already happening whenever it is needed, else it would have given errors about that too.

Comment: Just a guess: try `print(type(k), k)`.

Comment: it returns:
    [lua] string 1

Comment: The string `"1"` and the number `1` are two different keys in Lua even though they look the same when printed. Your `self.exce[1]` uses the number `1` while `self.exce[k]` apparently uses the string `"1"`.

Comment: Converting the id to a string when storing it works, but now im confused cuz in another script I did the exact same code without having to convert it to a string...

Comment: maybe in that case it was a string to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting together a couple different comments and your code here, it looks like the index value of the array in some particular iteration of the "for in pairs" loop (or perhaps all of them, but I'll touch on that in a minute) is a string instead of an integer.

To summarize if you don't want to read the entire thing, "for k, v in pairs" loops will iterate through an entire array, setting `k` to the index of the value `v`. It appears your "for in pairs" loop is attempting to iterate through a value of nil where `k` is a string instead of an integer. You may also want to look into using `ipairs` instead of `pairs` in your for loop.

The value of `someArray[1]`is different than the value of `someArray["1"]`.
The index `[1]` is a completely different index than the index `["1"]` for any given array.
A simple fix would be to use

```
ind = tonumber(k)
print(self.exce[ind])
```

This converts the string `k` to a number type. Be aware this may throw an error if `k` is a non-numerical string. If the array has any values where the index is a non-numerical string, you may get an error. As the other answer suggests, converting the index `k` to a string instead of an integer would work as well, and would not throw errors if you used a non-numerical value for your indices.

My guess as to why this is happening would be that the function that you're using to store your data to an array, `filterExceptions.server_onException( self, id )`, is being passed a string instead of an integer, which would result in the k value being set to a string in that particular iteration of the "for in pairs" loop.

To help better understand this, here's a bit of example code:

```
a = {true, false, false}
a[1] = true
a["1"] = true

print("Raw for in pairs loop")
for k, v in pairs (a) do
  print(type(k)..k)
end

print("For in pairs converting k to a number")
for k, v in pairs (a) do
  ind = tonumber(k)
  print(type(ind)..ind)
end

print("For in ipairs")
--which I'm not sure I completely understand but 
--it seems to skip over any iteration where k is not a number
for k, v in ipairs(a) do
  print(type(k)..k)
end
```

This code produces the following output:

```
Raw for in pairs loop   
number1 
number2 
number3 
string1 
For in pairs converting k to a number   
number1 
number2 
number3 
number1 
For in ipairs   
number1 
number2 
number3
```

EDIT: Not sure what's going on in the `self.math` table so I can't comment on that.

EDIT2: I'd also refer you to the following link: [lua: iterate through all pairs in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584258/lua-iterate-through-all-pairs-in-table)
The top answer there should help understand the difference between pairs and ipairs, if you don't already. You may want to use ipairs to prevent values of `k` where `v == nil` from being iterated through with pairs. pairs will iterate through every key/value pair, whereas ipairs will iterate through integer keys starting at 1 and going until it hits a nil value.

EDIT3: I'm sorry this is such a long answer...I just wanted to be thorough.

Answer (score 0):

It apears converting the id to a string fixes this, tough im still confused as to why this same code worked on another block and not this one.

```
function filterExceptions.server_onException( self, id )
local id2 = tostring(id)
if self.exce[id2] == nil then
    self.exce[id2] = true
    self.network:sendToClients( "client_onList", id )
else
    self.exce[id2] = true
    self.network:sendToClients( "client_offList", id )
end
end
```

Comment: You should decide whether your id is a string or a number and use this type consistently. The other place where things might have gone wrong is when storing the id in the self.math table ...